# Need help in Paris php quering

Tags: php, idiorm

Example:
I have following two classes for tables in database.

```
            class Post extends Model {}
            class User extends Model {
               public function posts() {
                   return $this->has_many('Post'); // Note we use the model name literally - not a    pluralised version
               }
            }
```

Now I want to quert all users and their associated posts in one variable.
something like that:

```
            $user = Model::factory('User')->find_many();
            // Find the posts associated with the user
            $posts = $user->posts()->find_many();
```

I want to get the result in **$posts** variable.

Comment: Have you got any errors? What is your output?

Comment: yes, it gives error post() function

Comment: What kind of error? Please edit your question with the full content of your error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue my self

```
            $user = Model::factory('User')->find_many();
            // Find the posts associated with the user
            //$posts = $user->posts()->find_many();
```

I looped through $user and passed each user id to $user->posts()->find_one();

sudo code is here:

```
            foreach($user as $usr)
            {
               $posts = $user->posts()->find_one($usr->Id);
            }
```

Comment: You must add your solution! Maybe there are other programmers who may have the same problem and needs your solution